# How to launch my Android app from a QR reader with the scheme like sfd:// i.e.,Customscheme instead of http?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, parameters

I want to know if it’s possible in android to start application using QR Code reader. The things that I want to achieve is :

I create QR Code and after scanning it with QR Code reader I need to start my application with some params,it looks something like this : 
sfd://?mt=promotion&id=12

Is there anyway to achieve this and to get the param which is build in the qr code with the intent for launching the application?.

Comment: yes! As you have already mentioned in your question title, use custom scheme that the android provides.

Answer (score 0):

You can add android:data in the manifest like this

```
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.HomeActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:scheme="sfd" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

but be careful because you don't own the sfd scheme there is a possibility that another people will use the same scheme.